# Application Icon path in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, icons

How do you access the Application Icon path in MS Access 2003 programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a custom property ("AppIcon") of the database object.

```
Set dbs = CurrentDb
sAppIconPath = dbs.Properties("AppIcon")
```

Note -  you will get an error if the property doesn;t exist.

This code from the Access Help shows how to create the property:

Example

The following example shows how to change the AppIcon and AppTitle properties in a Microsoft Access database (.mdb). If the properties haven't already been set or created, you must create them and append them to the Properties collection by using the CreateProperty method.

```
Sub cmdAddProp_Click()
    Dim intX As Integer
    Const DB_Text As Long = 10
    intX = AddAppProperty("AppTitle", DB_Text, "My Custom Application")
    intX = AddAppProperty("AppIcon", DB_Text, "C:\Windows\Cars.bmp")
    CurrentDb.Properties("UseAppIconForFrmRpt") = 1
    Application.RefreshTitleBar
End Sub

Function AddAppProperty(strName As String, _
        varType As Variant, varValue As Variant) As Integer
    Dim dbs As Object, prp As Variant
    Const conPropNotFoundError = 3270

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    On Error GoTo AddProp_Err
    dbs.Properties(strName) = varValue
    AddAppProperty = True

AddProp_Bye:
    Exit Function

AddProp_Err:
    If Err = conPropNotFoundError Then
        Set prp = dbs.CreateProperty(strName, varType, varValue)
        dbs.Properties.Append prp
        Resume
    Else
        AddAppProperty = False
        Resume AddProp_Bye
    End If
End Function
```