# Change Display Control property of a yes/no field to be a check box using VBA

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a table that is imported from an external access database via VBA that has a check box in a Yes/No type field. This check box allows users to perform complex actions on items selected in the table by clicking a button. The issue I am running into is that when the table gets imported the Yes/No field becomes a text field instead of a check box. Is there any way to change the field back to being a check box instead of a text field?

Code used to import table:

```
Dim SQL as String
Dim DBS as Database

Set DBS as CurrentDB

SQL = "SELECT [Cost Down Table].* INTO [Cost Down TableX9] FROM [Cost Down Table] IN """"[MS Access;DATABASE=" & FilePath & "]"
DBS.Execute SQL
```

The check box is changed when the table is imported into the user database. The checkbox is in a datasheet/table, not a form control.

Code attempting to change field to text box:

`Me.CurrentItemsSubFrm.Controls("Select").Properties("DisplayControl") = acCheckBox`

This gives me RTE 2455 "You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property "DisplayControl".

**Edit -**

My specific working solution using @Andre's feedback is as follows:

```
Dim prpNew As Property
Set prpNew = DBS.TableDefs("Cost Down TableX9").Fields("Select").CreateProperty("DisplayControl", dbInteger, acCheckBox)
DBS.TableDefs("Cost Down TableX9").Fields("Select").Properties.Append prpNew
DBS.TableDefs("Cost Down TableX9").Fields("Select").Properties("DisplayControl") = acCheckBox

Me.CurrentItemsSubFrm.SourceObject = "Cost Down TableX9"
```

Comment: What is changing the checkbox to a textbox in the first place?  Is the checkbox in a table(Cost Down TableX9) on a worksheet?

Comment: The check box is changed when the table is imported into the user database. The checkbox is in a datasheet/table, not a form control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you must set the `DisplayControl` property of the **table field** before loading the table into the subform.

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs("Cost Down TableX9").Fields("Select").Properties("DisplayControl") = acCheckBox
```

**Edit**

If the DisplayControl has never been set in table design, it must be created with the `CreateProperty` method.

This answer has an example of how to check for existence and (if not) append a property:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/698492/3820271

Comment: `CurrentItemsSubFrm` is an unbound subform that is populated by the table `Cost Down TableX9` by changing the source object on load `Me.CurrentItemsSubFrm.SourceObject = Cost Down TableX9` so I can't change the control in design view since there isn't one to change.

Comment: What you said makes sense, but when I try to run the code I am getting RTE 3270 - "Property not found." I've been searching through MSDN to see if they have something on it but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: Apparently you have to define the property before it can be used, but your code is correct after defining the property.

Comment: @110SidedHexagon: yes. :) See edit and the linked answer.