# Changing icon on Microsoft Access database

Tags: ms-access, icons

This has been driving me crazy, and I really don't understand why it doesn't work...
I am trying to change the icon for my Access database using VBA, and it /almost/ works.

I am using the following code in the OnOpen event of my startup form:

```
    CurrentDb.Properties("AppIcon").Value = CurrentProject.Path & "\favicon.ico"
    CurrentDb.Properties("UseAppIconForFrmRpt").Value = True
    Application.RefreshTitleBar
```

The icon shows up in the titlebar and main Access window just fine, however, the icon does NOT show up on forms. The weird thing is: It DOES show up on reports. Can anyone fill me in on what the H is going on? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I just tested this by changing icon via VBA, and my Form icon changed.  If a form is already open, the form icon turns to blank, but closing and reopening form display correct icon.

Comment: That is so weird. I have tried everything. No luck

Comment: Why would user need to do this? Are you saying that reopening form still does not display icon? Does the db have this property already set in Options?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application Icon path in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698418/application-icon-path-in-ms-access)

Comment: Well using the code I posted in my original post brings no issues at all, and the icon shows up on the main Access window and reports in print preview. Just not on my forms... They all just show the Access logo icon.

Comment: I am not using "UseAppIconForFrmRpt" line and icon shows on forms and reports. Have to reopen form that runs code to show on that form.