# Change application icon on Microsoft Access database not working

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm using this code:

```
Application.CurrentProject.Properties.Add "AppIcon", Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\myicon.ico"
Application.RefreshTitleBar
```

to change the application icon of my access database, but the Access icon is still displayed in the main, like this:

[image]

Forms and reports are updated with the customized Icon, but not the "main" icon as shown.

I have tried to use different code, like this:

```
CurrentDb.Properties("AppIcon").Value = CurrentProject.Path & "\myicon.ico"
Application.RefreshTitleBar
```

But still no updates for the "application" icon.

PS:
This code has been working for several years, but lately it is not updating the "application" Icon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application Icon path in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698418/application-icon-path-in-ms-access)

Comment: I have tried the suggested solution but still the same problem... : No updates for the "application" icon